# cloudinary img format breaks google page speed mobile

Tags: image, mobile, pagespeed, cloudinary

I run google PageSpeed tests weekly against both production and staging websites. For the last few weeks mobile has consistently produced the dreaded '?' result. The typical cloudinary img format used has been:

```
<img data-src="https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/h_460,w_700/q_auto,f_auto/v1592516862/image-name-01.jpg" alt="descriptive text" class="cld-responsive">
```

While gtmetrix has tested well with this format, I found the inclusion of dimensions (h_460,w_700) in the  embed are what produce '?' for mobile using google PageSpeed. Repetetive tests may finally produce an actual mobile score but it's wildly inconsistent. Has anyone encountered this and found an explanation or solution?

Comment: Why are you stacking the transforms? Does h_460,w_700_q_auto,f_auto (single transform - no slash between) change anything? I doubt it. But...

Comment: We had tried many cloudinary suggested transforms to see which perform better. Using the combo `h_460,w_700/q_auto,f_auto` was producing smaller image sizes than either alone.

Answer (score 1):

After working with cloudinary support we found it was the use of their responsive class that was causing issues with google PageSpeed. We landed on using srcset instead, something like this:

`<img sizes="(min-width: 40em) 50em, 100vw" srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto,w_256/v1602025945/image-name-01.jpg 256w, https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto,w_512/v1602025945/image-name-01.jpg 512w, https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto,w_598/v1602025945/image-name-01.jpg 598w" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/companyname/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto,w_598/v1602025945/image-name-01.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="descriptive text" />`

Works really well, improved performance greatly.